# Rails cant be found after installing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, I installed Rails yesterday and used it quite a bit. Today after booting up my computer it indicates that rails is not installed when i use rails commands

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
   * ruby-railties-3.2
   * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Ruby 1.9.3p484 is installed as well as RVM 1.29.3.

Not sure if this is a $PATH problem or something else. I also tried to run `gem install rails` but that returned:

```
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.
```

Did anyone else have this problem before?

Comment: If you are just getting started with rails note that you are using a fairly old version of ruby. Currently 2.5 is the latest version. While rvm will get the job done, take a look at rbenv. Many rails devs prefer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

run `/bin/bash --login` in new terminal

then check the rails version `rails -v`

if rails version displayed correctly, you need to run `/bin/bash --login` for every new terminal window to use rails